# Running out of space restoring a file with Duplicity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, duplicity, dejadup

I'm trying to restore a `VDI` file for VirtualBox from a Duplicity backup. The `VDI` file is about 40 GB. I have 189 GB (including `~/.cache/duplicity` that is fully synced) of free space when I start the restore in the drive I try to restore the file to.

I'm running the following command:

`duplicity -t [date] --file-to-restore "[path_to_file_i_like_restore]" "sftp://[path_backup_location]" "[path_to_where_i_like_to_restore_the_file" --tempdir=~/.cache/tmp`

which returns:

`Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.`

`Error '[Errno 28] No space left on device' patching .`

Why is it running out of space? Is there anything I can do to make it not running out of space?

I'm only running the restore command when I'm trying to restore the file to make sure that there is as much space as possible available.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: was the file much bigger than 40GB at any point in the past? any specific reason why you specify your TEMPDIR to be '~/.cache/tmp' ? can you provide a 'df -h' output of your system? ..ede/duply.net

Comment: I mounted an external drive and used it as `TEMPDIR` and then it worked.